# AFK Nickname remove when a person chat in discord

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm currently doing a code with [AFK] when they type `${prefix}afk`, I wanted to do is after they chat again in discord the [AFK] in their nickname would be removed. So far this is only I know adding [AFK] in their nickname when they call the command

Here's my current code:

```
var nickname = `[AFK]`;


 message.member.setNickname(nickname + ' ' + message.author.username);
  const embed = new MessageEmbed()
  .setAuthor({iconURL: `${message.author.avatarURL()}`,name: `${message.member.user.tag}`})
  .setDescription(`${message.author.toString()}` + " is now AFK")
  .setTimestamp()
  .setColor('RANDOM')
  
   return message.channel.send({embeds: [embed]})
  //I wanted to do the next line when the person chat again [AFK] will be removed
```

`${prefix}afk` = `[AFK] Username` after chatting again `[AFK] Username` = `Username`

Any tips on how to do it? I'm using discord js v13 and slappey

This is the full code I'm doing right now:

```
  module.exports = class TestCommand extends BaseCommand {
  constructor() {
    super('test', 'testing', []);
  }

async run(client, message, args) {
 // if(!message.member.permissions.has("ADMINISTRATOR")) return message.channel.send("You can't use this command.");
// if(!message.guild.me.permissions.has("ADMINISTRATOR")) return message.channel.send("My role does not have the manage channels permission");
  const { MessageEmbed, Collection } = require('discord.js');
  var nickname = `[AFK]`;
  
  message.member.setNickname(nickname + ' ' + message.author.username);
  const embed = new MessageEmbed()
  .setAuthor({iconURL: `${message.author.avatarURL()}`,name: `${message.member.user.tag}`})
  .setDescription(`${message.author.toString()}` + " is now AFK")
  .setTimestamp()
  .setColor('RANDOM')
  
   return message.channel.send({embeds: [embed]})
  }
}
```

Take note that I'm using slappey package to do my bot.

Answer (score 0):

If the username includes "[AFK]" you can remove the AFK tag from the user.

Here's an example for you:

```js
const nickname = `[AFK]`

if (message.author.username.includes(nickname)) {
  const newNickname = message.author.username.split(nickname)[1]
  message.member.setNickname(newNickname)
} else {
  message.member.setNickname(nickname, message.author.username)
  const embed = new MessageEmbed()
  .setAuthor({iconURL: `${message.author.avatarURL()}`, name: `${message.member.user.tag}`})
  .setDescription(`${message.author.toString()}` + " is now AFK")
  .setTimestamp()
  .setColor('RANDOM')
  
    return message.channel.send({embeds: [embed]})
  }
```

NOTE: As you want user has to write `${prefix}afk` command again to remove his AFK tag.

EDIT:

You need to add this code to your index.js file

```js
client.on("messageCreate", async (message) => {
  if (message.author.username.includes("[AFK]")) {
    const newNickname = message.author.username.split("[AFK]")[1]
    message.member.setNickname(newNickname)
  }
});
```

Comment: Is there no other way when user chat random chats the AFK tag will be removed? Cause dyno can do I'm confused how dyno do that

Comment: Yes, you can do it but I have to see more things. Simply you can move ```if (message.author.username.includes(nickname)) {
  const newNickname = message.author.username.split(nickname)[1]
  message.member.setNickname(newNickname)
} ``` this part to top of the ```messageCreate``` event.

Comment: So i will put it on `client.on or bot.on`?

Comment: Put it which one you're using right now. Both will work I guess

Comment: I will try now thanks, I'll be back

Comment: Okay. I'm looking forward to hearing from you :)

Comment: Didn't work since the `message.member.setNickname(newNickname)` can't find the `messageCreate` event, I tried the `if and else` statement aswell it didn't work

Comment: Hmm. I need to see your all code for helping.

Comment: Still not working, I tried it to before but still not :/ That's why I'm really confused

Comment: Hmm sorry... :(

Comment: It's okay! Thanks for helping

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove a member's nickname, you can simply set their nickname as `null`. Example:

```js
message.member.setNickname(null);
```

This is a much simpler and efficient method of removing a guild member's nickname.

You could also check to see if the nickname includes "[AFK]" then remove it. So your code becomes:

```js
  module.exports = class TestCommand extends BaseCommand {
  constructor() {
    super('test', 'testing', []);
  }

async run(client, message, args) {
 // if(!message.member.permissions.has("ADMINISTRATOR")) return message.channel.send("You can't use this command.");
// if(!message.guild.me.permissions.has("ADMINISTRATOR")) return message.channel.send("My role does not have the manage channels permission");
  const { MessageEmbed, Collection } = require('discord.js');
  var nickname = `[AFK]`;
  if (message.member.nickname?.includes(nickname)) {
      message.member.setNickname(null); // remove nickname
      return message.reply({ content: `Welcome back ${message.author}! I have removed your AFK.` });
  }
  message.member.setNickname(nickname + ' ' + message.author.username);
  const embed = new MessageEmbed()
  .setAuthor({iconURL: `${message.author.avatarURL()}`,name: `${message.member.user.tag}`})
  .setDescription(`${message.author.toString()}` + " is now AFK")
  .setTimestamp()
  .setColor('RANDOM')
  
   return message.channel.send({embeds: [embed]})
  }
}
```

## Solution

> Ah I mean if everytime the user use the `${prefix}afk` then the [AFK] will be added in their nickname, but if the user cameback chatting randomly the [AFK] will be remove in their nickname – @新Acesyyy
> (Question author)

To achieve this, you must add the following code into the top of your `messageCreate` event:

```js
  if (message.member?.nickname?.includes("[AFK]")) {
      message.member.setNickname(null); // remove nickname
      return message.reply({ content: `Welcome back ${message.author}! I have removed your AFK.` });
  }
```

Comment: Should I do `if(statement)` and `else statement?`

Comment: I've updated my answer with the code for your command. I made changes so that if the nickname includes `[AFK]`, it will remove the nickname and will send a welcome back message.

Comment: I will try it now be right back

Comment: I tried and still not working. :/

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"! Is there an error? Also note that it'll only remove your nickname if it included "[AFK]"

Comment: Yes, when the user have "[AFK]" in their name, after typing again its not removing

Comment: What do you mean?
If a user does: `${prefix}afk``, the bot sets their nickname to `[AFK] ${message.author.username}`.
They then type `${prefix}afk` again, and does the bot remove the nickname? If the bot removes the nickname, then there shouldn't be an issue??

I need to know what you mean

Comment: Ah I mean if everytime the user use the `${prefix}afk` then the [AFK] will be added in their nickname, but if the user cameback chatting randomly the [AFK] will be remove in their nickname

Comment: Oh! I misinterpreted, my bad. I will update my answer

Comment: I've updated my answer with the code that you'll need to include!

Comment: After trying the edited answer, it still need to type `?afk` again to remove the [AFK] in the nickname. Maybe if I try `args[0]` should do the work? or something?

Comment: Can you send me your code? You need to add the code from the edited answer in your messageCreate event. It needs to at the top, otherwise the if conditions and other logic will filter the message out (as the message being sent might not be a command). Once you have done this, please send me your resulting code.

Comment: Its alright i made another code line which is using mongoose